# I need to backup userprofiles with a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I need to backup my userprofile with a PowerShell script. I've got it somehow to work, but when the copy finishes the output looks really weird. No new folder gets generated.

Output:

[image: folder screenshot]

```cs
$Destination = Read-Host "Please type the path directory you want to copy the backup files" #destination
$Folder = Read-Host "Please type the root name folder" #name of backup folder
$validation = Test-Path $Destination #validate the destination if it has the privileges

New-PSDrive -Name "Backup" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Destination #temporary folder for the backup
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination\$Folder

if ($validation -eq $true) { 
    Set-Location Backup:
} else {
    Write-Host "Error!Run Script Again"
    break
}

robocopy "$env:UserProfile\desktop\" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\pictures\" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\documents\" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec

function Pause {
    Write-Host "Backup Sucessfull!!! `n"
}

Pause
```

Comment: This is probably because the backslash in $Destination\$Folder is not being taken as a literal. But I don't use robocopy enough to really say. You might want to try to create your robocopy arguments as seperate strings then pass them to robocopy as variables.

Comment: What *exactly* does "output looks really weird" mean? What is the result you expect? How is the result you actually get different from what you expected? Enable `robocopy` logging and check the log for errors/warnings.

Comment: Try using `Join-Path` for combining `$Destination\$Folder`

Comment: Sorry for not saying exactly what weird is, I want the cript to create a new folder, and look somehow it's not even copying all to the same path.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/30bb8a61d6bfe8d7e0dc2abff0eaee40

Comment: https://gyazo.com/95985f7de87508c341035b5f28cc2b13

Comment: + Why are Music and Videos copied and the desktop isn't copied.

It makes all no sense, and the folders Music and Videos are not able to be opened in this directory.

I'm loosing my mind it makes no sens
@AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Please include everything that is relevant for your question in your question. I'm not going to enable JavaScript for some random site just so I can troubleshoot your problem. Also, did you follow my advice and run `robocopy` with logging enabled? What does the log say?